# Calendar Control in iOS

Tags: ios, calendar, tapku

I am looking to have a calendar control in one of the view controllers in my app. I have looked around and found Kal and Tapku as the popular ones. I was able to integrate Kal into my project, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want to.

What I am looking for is - 
1. The font color, cell color, font bold/italics etc. should be customizable through the API.
2. I should be able to segue to another view controller from any cell (i.e. date)
3. I should be able to display some more controls on the screen.. such as a few labels, etc.

Is it possible to get any such pre-existing 3rd party calendar control which I can customize to suit my needs? Or would I need to create my own calendar control?

Answer (score 3):

Look at my opensource calendar component: https://github.com/k06a/ABCalendarPicker

Comment: where the documentation of your library

Answer (score 1):

My open source calendar should be able to do all those

https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar

Although not thorough the API, you can customize the fonts and every other UI by editing the constants in SACalendarConstants.h

You can segue to another view by implementing a delegate function

```
-(void) SACalendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didSelectDate:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year
```

This will get called every time the cell is clicked. You can then launch a segue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the control offered by Rescoe? It isn't free, and I haven't evaluated it personally but in my experience with their stuff on other platforms (i.e. Windows Mobile), they are quite robust.

http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/details.aspx?comp=MonthCalendar&p=iOS

Edit: the control requires Mono touch, which may not be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

In case of Kal you will have to make changes in the KalTileView.m, its where you can set the background images and font colors (within the drawRect method).

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of them from here -
[Code4App Calendars](http://code4app.net/category/calendar)